# Nestjs cant resolve dependencies of EmailConfirmationController

Tags: nestjs

I am new to NESTJS and keep getting this error:

[Nest] 26563  - 16/08/2022 09:25:22   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the EmailConfirmationController (?). Please make sure that the argument EmailConfirmationService at index [0] is available in the EmailConfirmationModule context.

link to my repository: https://github.dev/GuilhermeVozniak/CP

Answer (score 1):

In your `EmailConfirmationController` make sure you are using `import { EmailConfirmationService } from './email-confirmation.service'` instead of `import { EmailConfirmationService } from './email-Confirmation.service'`. File name is important here. I tried cloning your repo and it failed on Linux.